# Spree - Deface - Edit Product - Giving Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am working on my eCommerce site and have selected Spree (Ruby on Rails) although I am converged with PHP and .NET. It has been so far fascinating out of the box and yesterday I was interested in adding a featured product to the home page.

**Spree Version: 1.3.2**

For that I did some changes to Spree. They are as follows:

1. Migrations - add `is_featured:boolean` field to the spree_products table
2. bundle exec rake db:migrate
3. Extending the `Spree::Product` class
4. Using `Deface` to add a check-box to the `edit` view.

As far as I am concerned 1, 2, 3 have gone fine as I have tested them via the `rails console`. As I understand the error comes in the 4th step when I try to add the check box.

`overrides/featured_checkbox_admin_product.rb`

```
Deface::Override.new(
  :virtual_path   => "spree/admin/products/_form",
  :name           => "featured_checkbox_admin_product",
  :insert_bottom  => "[data-hook='admin_product_form_additional_fields']",
  :text           => "
    <%= f.field_container :is_featured do %>
      <%= f.label :is_featured %>
      <%= f.check_box :is_featured %> 
    <%= end %>"
)
```

I am new to Rails and am looking in to documentation while working. But as I understand the code is correct. Here is the error that is generated.

```
/home/ziyan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/spree_core-1.3.2/app/views/spree/admin/products/_form.html.erb:141: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
...');@output_buffer.append= ( end );@output_buffer.safe_concat...
...                               ^
/home/ziyan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/spree_core-1.3.2/app/views/spree/admin/products/_form.html.erb:153: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')'
/home/ziyan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/spree_core-1.3.2/app/views/spree/admin/products/_form.html.erb:155: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
Extracted source (around line #141):

138:     <%= f.field_container :is_featured do %>
139:       <%= f.label :is_featured %>
140:       <%= f.check_box :is_featured %> 
141:     <%= end %>
142: </div>
143: 
144:   <div class="clear"></div>
```

What I understand is `Deface` has worked. But the code I'd entered is the one causing the problem.

Would appreciate any help on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove unnecessary `=` from last line, leave just

```
<% end %>
```

and it should works.